# Unconfirmed Transaction? Money does not show in wallat

Tags: transactions

I have tried researching this, and still cannot find an optimal solution/explanation.

My Wallet ID: 16B64JvCNBDHsEXeuE6Ao4g1tZDb9zyyQ8
ID of the wallet I sent the money to (also mine) 1JeFKHt65R8pQjXhChZGsUGpHizYDPLeXZ
Transaction:ID: 98057df05a8df30beb338aac8183df82dc44a1300d141aac04b388be8005818c

The payment is still unconfirmed? It has been a full day now, and this is really needed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or a clue on the time frame this will take to be confirmed?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ou have set a fee that is way too low.   This tends to happen if you are using an older version of whatever wallet your are using.  The newest version of a wallet do not allow you to set a fee that will get you into trouble.  I will try to enter your transaction into the ViaBTC accelerator, that usually will do the trick.   I suggest that you upgrade to the latest version, and make sure that your fee is of a reasonable amount.  Here is a site that shows you what the current wait time are for confirmation based on fee amount.   https://bitcoinfees.21.co/